# limits of Surface area of revolution in polar co-ordinates.

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

My Question is Find the area of the surface generated by revolving the right-hand loop of the lemniscate $\;r^2=\cos2\theta\;$ about the vertical line through the origin (y-axis). I know the formula

$$S=2\pi \int_\alpha^\beta r \cos\theta\sqrt{r^2+\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^2}\,d\theta$$
But I cant figure out the limits $\alpha$ and $\beta$. in Cartesian co-ordinate I can easily picture a function segment from a to b and imagine it rotating around any axis, but In polar I am really having difficulty in capturing the limits and than imaging a line segment then rotating the segment around y-axis.I just cant picture it in my mind. any help? thanks in advance.

Comment: @amWhy There should be a root , and also how do I use these symbols?

Comment: You're right, I omitted the root. Is it around the whole integrand?  Did I get it right now? This is mathjax formatting, which you can learn on the site. It's LaTeX enclosed in dollar signs.

Comment: Yes. Its right now. thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate the right-hand loop of the lemniscate $r^2=\cos(2\theta)$, you need to let $\theta$ vary from $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $\frac{\pi}{4}$; i.e. $\theta \in [-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4}] $. To see this, we have

$$ r = \bar{+} \sqrt{\cos(2 \theta) } \implies \cos(2\theta)\geq 0 \implies -\frac{\pi}{2}\leq2\theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}\implies -\frac{\pi}{4}\leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{4}. $$

Here is the plot

[image]

Here is the full graph

[image]

Comment: Mhenni, isn't that cosine negative in part of that interval?

Comment: What is meant by a right hand loop?

Comment: and thanks for the plot.I wouldnt have understood it without the graph :D

Comment: @TamimAdDari: Because it has two loops. See the other graph.

Comment: @TamimAdDari: You are welcome.

Comment: @RonGordon: It should be $[-\pi/4,\pi/4]$. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

That branch of the lemniscate is generated by setting $\alpha = -\pi/4$ and $\beta = \pi/4$. You can see this by following the curve from $\theta=0$ at $r=1$ to where $r=0$ at $\theta=\pi/4$, and realizing the symmetry about the $x$ axis.

It turns out that the integral works out quite nicely,although as you have not asked for help in evaluating it, I will leave it to you to see how it all works out.

Comment: But, for this I have to plot the curve. I understand this and I can picture now. Is there any way of doing it without plotting the graph? and BTW, I have evaluated the Integral 2sqrt(2)pi isnt it?

Comment: @TamimAdDari: bingo.  (Yes)